# Is $F$ applied to the water or applied to the hose?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

At the outlet of the garden hose, is the force $F$, which is opposite to the direction of the water flow, applied to the water, or is it applied to the hose?  I think $F$ is applied to the water in the hose, not to the hose.  The only force exerted on the hose is the force perpendicular to the pipe wall and the friction force of the water parallel to the pipe wall.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a short hose attached to a cubic container and a cork at the outlet. If the cork is then removed, this is what would happen:

There is pressure acting in all directions in the water and on the surfaces of the container.

The water near the outlet (A) would have a force from this pressure acting on it to the left, but nothing pushing it to the right, so it accelerates and moves out to the left.

The water pressure acts on the walls of the container, all of the right wall (B) is pushed to the right.  All of the left wall is pushed left except the area where there is a hole for the outlet pipe.

[image]

Therefore there is more force acting right and a resultant force to the right on the container (but not on the outlet pipe).  The resultant force is equal and opposite to the force that accelerated the water.

If the pipe was longer and curved there would be a similar resultant force acting on the hose to the right, due to the water pressure.

Comment: I suggest you have a picture, otherwise it's difficult to know what you're talking about.